# Twitter boostrap grid shows a white margin on the right of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a twitter boostrap fluid layout.  When the page loads, it looks fine, but then you notice that you can actually scroll to the right.  When you scroll to the right, a small white margin appears on the right of the page.

[image]

This codepen shows the issue http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AKygh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `row` div is open. Add a `</div>` at the end of this:

```
<div class="row" style="background-color: blue;">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">Text on right</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-4 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p class="lead">Some text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Here
`</div>`

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ghkce)

Answer (score 1):

try removing `<div class="container-fluid">`

Answer (score 0):

From the Bootstrap docs.. (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

> "Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be
>   immediate children of rows..."

So, since you have a `row` that is a child of a `row`.. just change the inner `row` to a full-width column (`col-xs-12`):

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/120519

Answer (score -1):

remove `margin-right:15px` from `bootstrap.css` on line number `757` class `.container-fluid`.. and remove `margin-right:-15px` from same css file on line `763` from class `.row`...

Comment: this doesnt require modifying Bootstrap - it requires conforming to their required HTML structure.

Comment: I have given the suggestion.. he can also use `inline or internal css` to do so.. @sevenseacat